# How to move decimal places in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to place a decimal between the first and second digit of the interest rate and keep 2 trailing after the decimal. How do I go about doing this?

```
SELECT TOP 10 l.PARENTACCOUNT AS [Account Number]
        , l.interestrate AS [Interest Rate]
FROM dbo.LOAN l
```

This is my current result:

```
Account Number  Interest Rate
0000000107       9900
0000000107       11900
0000002000       5750
0000002460       10300
0000002652       9900
0000003850       0
0000004942       7510
0000004942       4990
0000004942       5000
0000006652       6790
```

This is my desired result:

```
Account Number  Interest Rate
0000000107       9.90
0000000107       1.19
0000002000       5.75
0000002460       1.03
0000002652       9.90
0000003850       0.00
0000004942       7.51
0000004942       4.99
0000004942       5.00
0000006652       6.79
```

EDIT: I ended up using this to get the correct interest rate

```
ISNULL(convert(decimal(4, 2), stuff(convert(varchar(255), interestrate), 2, 0, '.')), 0)
```

Comment: With some basic math? As in InterestRate / 1000

Comment: cast it as a string and do simple string manipulation?

Comment: why marked down?  The Q seems to give explanation, plus input and output data requirements

Comment: Likely because the OP hasn't show their efforts to solve the problem themselves, and the data is an image, not `text`, @Cato . Images of data are very poorly received at the best of times.

Comment: My gut tells me the OP is not correct.  I suspect these are stored as basis points and divide by 1000 would do the trick.   I would LOVE to have a 1.03% rate on a loan... I believe the true rate is 10.30%

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Strange format; you cannot handle interest rates less than 1%.

You can do:

```
select convert(decimal(4, 2), stuff(convert(varchar(255), interestrate), 2, 0, '.'))
```

This converts the value to a number, adds the decimal place, and converts to a decimal.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b2eb978ff612622d1e1366b4d6daaf37) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Why not just do some math here? convert(decimal(9,2), interestrate / 1000.0) Seems pretty straight forward to me. But either works.

Comment: As someone mentioned above /1000 only works for up to 4 digits.

Comment: and the OP has said that they want left 1 of the number, then a point, then mid 2 for 2.  That said, I am not sure they have asked for the right thing because it means that their interest rates are limited to 1.00% to 9.99%

Comment: @AaronReese I like Gordon's answer, but I agree with you.  I really suspect these are stored as Basis Points.  I've seen it done before.

Comment: Seems the OP didn't ask the question very well and basic math was all that was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to divide by 1000 :

```
SELECT TOP 10 l.PARENTACCOUNT AS [Account Number]
       , (l.interestrate/1000) AS [Interest Rate] FROM dbo.LOAN l
```

Comment: This would not produce the desired result for the 5-digit numbers

Comment: In MSSQL if the value is stored as an integer and you divide by an an integer the result will be an integer.  You have to explicitly CAST() or CONVERT() at least one of the numerator and divisor to be the required precision.  Can't comment on whether the same applies to other RDBMS.

Comment: Converting to a decimal, then dividing by 1000 solved my issue. I don't know why I didn't think about that before.

Comment: @lexirainbow . . . You didn't think about it before because your question *explicitly* states that 10300 should be 1.03, not 10.3.  This does not correctly answer your question.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I apologize. I'm still new to this and was overwhelmed at the time with the amount of projects I have.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming interest rate is a string. You could try:

```
SELECT CONVERT(real,CONCAT(LEFT([Interest rate],1),'.', RIGHT([Interest rate],LEN([Interest rate])-1))) FROM [Table]
```